# How to pass date from JSP to Java using stripes framework?

Tags: java, jsp, datetime, jodatime, stripes

I'm using the Stripes Framework and am trying to get a DateTime from the jsp but for some reason the setter always gets null passed into it.

JSP snippet:

```
<stripes:form name="dateForm" action="some.actionBean.url">
    <stripes:hidden name="myDate" value="12-23-2015 12:00" />
</stripes:form>
```

ActionBean snippet:

```
private DateTime myDate;

public void setMyDate(DateTime date){
  //when the setter gets called date is null, but why?
  this.myDate = date;
}
public DateTime getMyDate(){
  return this.myDate;
}
```

I tried many things already, like

- tried to set the value to different time formats
- tried to have the
  setter take in a string and then convert to a DateTime(this didn't
  work because the string is also null)
- tried different stripes tags

no luck yet, What am I doing wrong?

I'm basically tapping in the dark because I can't find the Tag Lib documentation. On the [official site](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Home) it is linked to a [broken page](https://stripesframework.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Stripes%201.6.0/ws/stripes/target/site/tlddoc/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding into a `DateTime` object. Stripes has a built in `TypeConverter` for `Date` objects but not for `DateTime`.

When you change `myDate` to `java.util.Date` Stripes' `DateTypeConverter` will pick it up.

Otherwise, if for instance you need support for `joda.time.DateTime` you'll need to write your own custom TypeConverter (which you don't need because its printed below):

```
public class JodaDateTimeTypeConverter implements TypeConverter<DateTime> {

    @Override
    public DateTime convert(String input, Class<? extends DateTime> type, Collection<ValidationError> errors) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
        DateTime datetime = formatter.parseDateTime(input);
        return datetime;
    }

    @Override
        public void setLocale(Locale arg0) {
    }
}
```

And put this custom TypeConverter class in (one of) your Stripes Extension package(s) which can be defined in `web.xml` under the filter named `StripesFilter`.:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>Extension.Packages</param-name>
    <param-value>path.to.my.extensionpackage</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes total sense, I just had no idea how to do it. I already tried changing the paramaters in the getter and setter to Date and it works like a charm!

Comment: Happy to help. BTW I noticed some strange formatting in your code on the Stripes prefix `stripes:form:hidden` where it should be `stripes:hidden`. Tried to edit it but the edits got lost. And perhaps while you're at it add a [jodatime] or [datetime] tag. Probably other people will encounter the same problem one day - I did anyway.

Comment: I updated the question, not sure how that formatting got in there it was a copy and paste and from where I copied it it did not have these things. Thanks again!

Comment: I just sent a message to the Stripes mailing list about the missing docs. Hope they'll fix it soon.